# How to use namespaces in JAXB using EclipseLink MOXy?

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I have an XML like:

```
<message  xmlns:gtm="http:// www.example.com/working/gtm">
    <gtm:header>
    <someid></someid>
    <sometext></sometext>
    </gtm:header>
    <gtm:customer>0123456789</gtm:customer>
</message>
```

I am using `@XmlPath` mappings. but when I run the code I get this error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-25016] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A namespace for the prefix gtm:header was not found in the namespace resolver.
```

I wonder what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is an example of how you can map your use case with [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php).

**package-info**

First you need to set up the namespace information using the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation.  We will leverage the namespace prefixes specified with the `@XmlNs` annotation later with the `@XmlPath` annotation.

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace="http:// www.example.com/working/gtm",
    xmlns={
        @XmlNs(prefix="gtm", namespaceURI="http:// www.example.com/working/gtm")
    },
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED)
package forum10548370;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

**Message**

The `@XmlPath` annotation is used to specify an XPath based mapping with MOXy.  Since in the `@XmlSchema` annotation we specified `elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED`, the portions of the XPath without a prefix will not be namespace qualified.

```
package forum10548370;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name="message", namespace="")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Message {

    @XmlPath("gtm:header/someid/text()")
    private String id;

    @XmlPath("gtm:header/sometext/text()")
    private String text;

    @XmlElement(namespace="http:// www.example.com/working/gtm")
    private String customer;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to add a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html):

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```
package forum10548370;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Message.class);

        File xml = new File("src/forum10548370/input.xml");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Message message = (Message) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(message, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message xmlns:gtm="http:// www.example.com/working/gtm">
   <gtm:header>
      <someid></someid>
      <sometext></sometext>
   </gtm:header>
   <gtm:customer>0123456789</gtm:customer>
</message>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html